# Detect navigation controller content changes but ignore hiding/showing of the navigation controller itself

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I'm the UINavigationControllerDelegate for my app's main navigation controller. I'd like to know when the view controller shown by my navigation controller is about to change, and when it has changed. I currently use these delegate methods to find out:

```
// Called when the navigation controller shows a new top view controller via a push, pop or setting of the view controller stack.
optional func navigationController(navigationController: UINavigationController, willShowViewController viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool)
optional func navigationController(navigationController: UINavigationController, didShowViewController viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool)
```

Unfortunately, the navigation controller is contained in a view controller with a slide-out menu. The menu controller calls appearance transition methods on the main view controller so it receives `viewWillDisappear` when the menu is shown and `viewWillAppear`/`viewDidAppear` when the menu is hidden. Views contained in the navigation controller rely on these events to know when they're visible.

When `viewWillAppear` fires on the navigation controller itself, it calls `navigationController:willShowViewController:` on me. When `viewDidAppear` fires on the navigation controller, it calls `navigationController:didShowViewController:`.

Is there any way I can distinguish between my navigation controller presenting a different content view controller and the navigation controller itself being shown?

Comment: What object is the delegate? Is it a controller, and if so, where does it fit into the view controller hierarchy?

Comment: @rdelmar It's the AppDelegate, which manages some global state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can accomplish this by subclassing the navigation controller, and adding a BOOL property that you set in viewWillAppear,

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    self.willBeAppearing = YES;
}
```

In the delegate, check this property, and set it to NO in the didShowViewController: method, if it's currently YES,

```
-(void)navigationController:(RDNavController *)navigationController willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated {
    if (navigationController.willBeAppearing == NO) {
        NSLog(@"The controller is changing");
        // Do what you need to do when a new controller is about to appear
    }
}


-(void)navigationController:(RDNavController *)navigationController didShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated {
    if (navigationController.willBeAppearing == NO) {
        NSLog(@"The controller has changed");
        // Do what you need to do when a new controller has appeared
    }else{
        navigationController.willBeAppearing = NO;
    }
}
```

Notice that I changed the class of the passed in navigation controller in the delegate methods to my custom class.

Comment: I wish there were a non-hacky solution, but there might not be one. Seems like a reasonable enough workaround!